# Склонение женской эстонской фамилии Койдула

Tags: склонение-фамилий

Из Википедии:
[**Ли́дия Ко́йдула**](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%B9%D0%B4%D1%83%D0%BB%D0%B0,_%D0%9B%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%8F) — эстонская поэтесса, прозаик, основоположник эстонской драматургии.

Мнение [первое](http://prospekt.ee/zizn/556-v-nazvaniyah-ulic-po-sovetskim-tradiciyam-a-v-pasporte-kak-ponravitsya.html).
Сложнее обстоит дело с эстонскими фамилиями, оканчивающимися на безударный “А” (например, Койдула). В советское время сложилась традиция не склонять в русской речи эстонские и финские фамилии с безударным конечным “А”. В энциклопедических изданиях в те годы это правило строго соблюдали и писали, например, драматургия Л. Койдула, на ул. Л. Койдула и т. п.

Мнение [второе](http://www.koolibri.ee/download/?action=binary&id=3504) (стр. 9).
***Примечание.*** Не забудьте, что **не склоняются:**
2. Эстонские имена и фамилии (независимо от пола), оканчивающиеся на гласный звук, кроме имён на ***-а*** (например: была у Иви, Юло, но у Асты, Тийны; произведение Вильде, но пьеса Койдулы).

Хотелось бы узнать **ваше** мнение (мне ближе первое, "несклоняемое").

Comment: Ну вот Вайкуле явно не склоняется, а Койдула - прямо хочется взять и склонить.  Я бы склонил, в случае чего, не взирая на традиции советского союза, хотя это и будет, вероятнее всего, ошибкой. Но не склонить никак не получится.

Answer (score 2):

Есть! Нашла исследование феномена!

**[Улица Койдула или Койдулы?](http://prospekt.ee/zizn/556-v-nazvaniyah-ulic-po-sovetskim-tradiciyam-a-v-pasporte-kak-ponravitsya.html)**

> Возникают вопросы и при проникновении слов из эстонского языка в
>   русский. Ежедневно мы встречаем такие слова в названиях улиц, причём
>   больше всего разночтений вызывают улицы, названные в честь того или
>   иного человека: кто-то произносит, например, ул. Кереса или ул.
>   Пушкина, а кто-то - Кересе и даже Пушкини. Как правильно? Своё
>   экспертное мнение по просьбе “ВП” высказала заведующая лекторатом
>   русского языка и литературы Нарвского колледжа ТУ Ольга Бурдакова: -
>   Вопрос можно отнести к числу дискуссионных. К сожалению, современные
>   справочники, которые регламентировали бы способы передачи эстонских
>   названий улиц в русском  тексте, мне не известны. Однако существует
>   сложившаяся еще в советское время традиция, которой нет смысла
>   изменять. Суть этой традиции заключается в следующем. В большинстве
>   случаев названия улиц не переводятся, а транслитирируются, что хорошо
>   известно нарвитянам, например, ул. Раху, ул. Суур​ (а не ул. Мирная и
>   ул. Большая - прим. редакции). Исключение составляют улицы, названные
>   в честь великих людей. Эстонские имена и фамилии в названиях улиц
>   склоняются в соответствии с нормами русской грамматики (доходчивое
>   изложение этих норм можно найти на портале «Грамота.ру»
>   http://www.gramota.ru/class/istiny/istiny_8_familii/). Мужские
>   фамилии, оканчивающиеся на согласный, склоняются. Следовательно, в
>   русском тексте правильным является употребление ул. П. Кереса или ул.
>   Пауля Кереса (и, разумеется, ул. Пушкина, а не ул. Пушкини, которое в
>   тексте на русском языке выглядит как варваризм). Сложнее обстоит дело
>   с эстонскими фамилиями, оканчивающимися на безударный “А” (например,
>   Койдула). ***В советское время сложилась традиция не склонять в
>   русской речи эстонские и финские фамилии с безударным конечным “А”. В
>   энциклопедических изданиях в те годы это правило строго соблюдали и
>   писали, например, драматургия Л. Койдула, на ул. Л. Койдула и т. п.
>   Сегодня эта традиция в русской устной и письменной речи нередко
>   нарушается: фамилии на безударный “А” подводятся под 1-е склонение. В
>   отношении грамматических норм я традиционалист, поэтому предпочитаю
>   сама (и рекомендую всем) не изменять эстонские фамилии на безударный
>   “А” и писать ул. Лидии Койдула.***

Эта "я", что изучала феномен, по её же признанию, "традиционалист", потому и не склоняет.

А прогрессивное человечество, как известно, нетрадиционной ориентации и, стало быть, склоняет и будет склонять форева!

Comment: Осторожно! Пропаганда некоторых вариантов нетрадиционализма преследуется в Росии по закону :-)

Comment: Фу. Я ж про *прогрессивное человечество*, а ты про каких-то почетных профессоров РАН - Кирилку и Матвиену, позор и посмешище России.

Answer (score 1):

**Пьеса Койдулы.**

Вот что я нашел на [Грамоте](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/letters/71-rubric-482) (Источник: Н. А. Еськова. Трудности словоизменения существительных. Учебно-методические материалы к практическим занятиям по курсу «Язык современной печати». Госкомитет печати СССР. Всесоюзный институт повышения квалификации работников печати. М., 1990.):

> Склонение фамилий, оканчивающихся в исходной форме на гласные, не зависит от того, мужские они или женские.
>
> Все фамилии, кончающиеся на неударное а после согласных, **склоняются по первому склонению**: Рибера — Риберы, Рибере, Риберу, Риберой, Сенека — Сенеки и т.д.; так же склоняются Кафка, Спиноза, Сметана, Петрарка, Куросава, Глинка, Дейнека, Гулыга, Олеша, Нагнибеда, Окуджава и др. Все такие фамилии, независимо от происхождения, являются морфологически членимыми в русском языке, т. е. в них выделяется окончание -а.